# Basler Pylon camera API

Tags: c++, api, camera

In the c++ documentation for the pylon API, they use a loop to display the grabbed images. This code works fine:

//Basler-Pylon example

```
main()
{

    CInstantCamera camera( 
    CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice());
    camera.StartGrabbing( c_countOfImagesToGrab);
    while ( camera.IsGrabbing())
    {
        // Wait for an image and then retrieve it. A timeout of 
        5000 ms is used.
        camera.RetrieveResult( 5000, ptrGrabResult, 
        TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);
        Pylon::DisplayImage(1, ptrGrabResult);
    }

}
```

In my application I use the API by implementing a UseBasler class, 
it instantiates the camera in the constructor and then uses a function to display one frame at a time:

```
class UseBasler()
{
public: 
    CInstantCamera* camera;
    void DisplayOneFrame();

}


UseBasler::UseBasler()
{
    camera = new CInstantCamera(CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice());
    camera->StartGrabbing( c_countOfImagesToGrab);

}


void UseBasler::DisplayOneFrame()
{
    if ( camera->IsGrabbing())
    {
        // Wait for an image and then retrieve it. A timeout of 5000 ms is used.

        camera->RetrieveResult( 5000, ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);

        //Display image
    }
}
```

I am getting Acces violation in the function DisplayFrame at the line

camera->RetrieveResult( 5000, ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);

I would appreciate input on why I am getting this crash. By the way when I move the call to the function RetrieveResult
to the constrctor just after I create the camera, I don't get this crash.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue.

Comment: Maybe this problem comes up if the image retreiving is done from a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper class implementation misses **Pylon::CGrabResultPtr ptrGrabResult** declaration. Make private class field out of it.

I would be nice to add some cleanup on destructor, like **camera->Close()**. Generally, your class instance is holding an access to real device, which could i.e. get disconnected at times. Pylon API gives you several options to keep track of these changes to be implemented by your wrapper.